# Losing of points after removing of the post

Tags: support, reputation, editing, suggested-edits

Is it possible for a user to lose points of reputation which were never gained by him?

I mean situation when a user has reputation above 2k and some post is edited by him and then after some days the post is removed. So at the end he has not gained 2 points after the edit what would be a case for  the users below 2k but because he was one of the editors he loses two points after removing of the post..

Comment: If you haven't gained any points, how would you lose them? Losing points means that in the history of "how my reputation has changed" some entries are removed due to deletion of users, posts, or nullifying votes. If your history didn't have a "got 2 points for ...", then why would it suddenly have this removed?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have not +2 in the history for the edit but I received -2 for removal of the post. I don't understand that. Maybe +2 message was also removed?

Comment: It might have been a post you have edited a long time ago (read: before passing the 2k barrier).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hmm, maybe a long time ago.. however I can't find it .. a list of all edits is available...

Comment: If you give the link the post, I can look into that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok see https://math.stackexchange.com/users/334463/widawensen?tab=reputation and Non-negative integer solutions to x^2+y^2=2015 I'm just curious, never mind 2 points ..

Comment: No, don't give me the link to your reputation page. I cannot see removed posts there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What else I could give? This is the only trace of the post Non-negative integer solutions to x^2+y^2=2015

Comment: You should have an actual link to that post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actual link? According to the message  "-2  03:00  removed  Non-negative integer solutions to x2+y2=2015" it was removed.. I have nothing more..

Comment: Then I cannot help you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you Asaf for the try, I think that with the removal of the post it was also removed message about this +2. If it would be not the case the other possibility would be -2 in the case when the post was edited even without any gain, so it would rather discouraging..

Comment: @AsafKaragila Google says https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2218817

Comment: @epimorphic: Great. Then https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/801596 should be the reason the two points were removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2218817 was recently removed by the automated process which removes "dead posts". You have [suggested an edit which was accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/801596) on that post, and now it's gone.

Therefore, you're out by two points.

Comment: Thank you Asaf.